# Highcharts pattern fill in Column stacked with Next.js

Tags: next.js, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm currently incorporating Highcharts in my Next.js project for column chart, but my chart does not show the pattern-fill chart. Erasing the color: {} from down below codes will show the chart. Several ways I have tried to render the pattern fill column chart:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-pattern-fill
2. SVG pattern from Highcharts docs https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/pattern-fills
3. Highcharts PatternObject https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.PatternObject

4. Instead of using import, I have tried {CDN here....} using Next.js Head

Is there something missing the codes or any other ways to show the pattern fill?

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import patternFill from "highcharts-pattern-fill";

export default function Chart() {
  if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
    patternFill(Highcharts);
  }

  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: "column",
    },
    title: {
      text: "Column Chart with Stripped Bars",
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Apple",
        data: [7, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21],
        color: {
          pattern: {
            path: {
              d: "M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,8 l8,-8 M7,9 l2,-2",
              strokeWidth: 4,
            },
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling the same issue, two things that are needed to be fixed:

1. import patternFill from "highcharts/modules/pattern-fill";
2. Using plotOptions instead of using pattern inside the series

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import patternFill from "highcharts/modules/pattern-fill";

export default function Chart() {
  if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
    patternFill(Highcharts);
  }

  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: "column",
    },
    title: {
      text: "Column Chart with Stripped Bars",
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        color: {
          pattern: {
            path: {
              d: "M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11",
              strokeWidth: 4,
            },
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Apple",
        data: [7, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21],
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the correct solution. Pattern fills was added as a module in version 6.1.0 and the npm package is no longer supported. You can also set the pattern directly in the series, not only in plotOptions. Simply using plotOptions you can set the options for all series or for specific series types: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2exw9uk1/